# python: test GPSd socket (2947) can never connect second+ time

Tags: python, sockets, gpsd

my goal is to check if GPSd is running on port 2947 if it is check again in x seconds. if its not start GPSd then check again in X seconds.

my problem is it never passes/connects on the second++ time.

My code:

```
import socket
import os
import time

#Simply change the host and port values
host = 'localhost'
port = 2947

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

while 1:
 try:
  s.connect((host, port))
  s.shutdown(2)
  #s.close() DIDN'T WORK
  print "Success connecting to "
  print host + " on port: " + str(port)
  time.sleep(20)
 except:
  print "Cannot connect to "
  #os.system("sudo killall gpsd")
  #os.system("sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -n -F /var/run/gpsd.sock")
  print host + " on port: " + str(port)
  #os.system("sudo killall gpsd")
  #os.system("sudo gpsd /dev/ttyAMA0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock")
  time.sleep(3)
```

what i get:

Success connecting to
   localhost on port: 2947
   Cannot connect to
   localhost on port: 2947
   Cannot connect to
   localhost on port: 2947

i have tried everything i can think of but because i don't think i understand what is causing the issue is not much help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should call close after you call shutdown.

Comment: i tried 's.close()' after 's.shutdown(2)' but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're (re)calling  a `connect` on the same socket you shutdown 20 seconds before. Sadly, can't do that.

As for the docs for socket.shutdown say:

`"Lasciate ogne speranza, voi ch'intrate"`

This loosely translates:

```
socket.shutdown(how)

     Shut down one or both halves of the connection. If how is SHUT_RD,
further receives are disallowed. If how is SHUT_WR, further sends are
disallowed. If how is SHUT_RDWR, further sends and receives are disallowed.
```

'socket.close()` Is more final than that:

```
all future operations on the socket object will fail.
```

You could just move `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)` into the loop after the `try` statement...I just don't know why you would want to proceed in this direction.